# why do we need customization on HP ALM?

Tags: alm, hp-alm

I would like to know the reason for HP ALM providing OTA / Rest API? Why do HP ALM product give API? Why do user needs customization on HP ALM?

Are there any limitations on using the HP ALM product directly? If we do customization what are the benefits we get?

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get benefits when you need to achieve something which you can not do without customization. E.g. if you need to store additional information, or if you want to prevent the user from doing something he or she should not do, or whatever the way you work requires you to do. It just better fits your needs.

The OTA or REST API is extremly useful if you use other tools you like to integrate with ALM and if you want to import or export stuff to ALM. Or when you need to do repetitive tasks—it could be used like a scripting language and is very handy sometimes.